# how to change uiimage's image on button click in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying change an uiimage control's containing image by clicking a button in swift. For this, i wrote a simple a "guess how many fingers i'm holding up" app. I've read some stackoverflow articles but couldn't solve the problem. Below you can see my code and my ui. How can i change change image on click?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func clickedGuessButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Guess button clicked")
        var randomX = Int(arc4random()%6)
        println("randomX = \(randomX)")
        var guess = inputField.text.toInt();

        let image0 = UIImage(named: "images/qm.jpg")
        let image1 = UIImage(named: "images/tick.jpg")
        let image2 = UIImage(named: "images/cross.jpg")

        if((inputField.text) != nil){
            if(guess == randomX){
                println("correct")
                myImageView.image=UIImage(named: "tick.jpg") // THIS IS NOT WORKING
                myImageView.image=image1                     // THIS IS NOT WORKING TOO
                inputField.resignFirstResponder();// hides keyboard
            }
            else
            {
                println("wrong")
                myImageView.image=UIImage(named: "cross.jpg")
                inputField.resignFirstResponder();//hides keyboard
            }
        }
        else{
            println("invalid input. requires integer only")
            inputField.resignFirstResponder();// hides keyboard
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And here's my UI:

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You don't need to specify either the asset catalog's name or the image file's extension. Try removing those. For example,

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
```

Comment: As of Swift 4 on Xcode 9 beta 3, do we now need to include the extensions e.g. ".jpeg"?

Comment: @AllisterBah Nope. No need to specify file extensions.

Answer (score 6):

It may depend on the version of Xcode you are using. For me the following worked:

```
ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Elephants.jpg")
```

Comment: Apparently that didn't work for the author of the question. Can you give more specific details on what version this might work (e.g. what you are using)?

Answer (score -13):

In Swift:

```
myImageView = "nameOfImage";
```

Comment: that's lightweight swift buddy. you didn't even call the type of UIImage.

Comment: Change it to this: `myImageView: UIImage = UIImage(name: "nameOfImage")` and then add a little explanation. This needs to be updated... Either way it was answered. But I would recommend updating the answer.